# Mongodb: How to query nested documents and top level documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following documents. Note that the top level document has `ID` and `attribute1` in common with `subDocument`.

```json
{
    "ID": "1",
    "attribute1": "123",
    "subDocument": [
      {
        "ID": "2",
        "attribute1": "456",
      },
      {
        "ID": "3",
        "attribute1": "567",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": "4",
    "attribute1": "123",
    "subDocument": [
      {
        "ID": "5",
        "attribute1": "456",
      }
    ]
  }
```

Now I need to have a query that can search based on `ID` and `attribute1`. If I give `ID` =1,`attribute1`="123", it should return the first top level document like following:

```json
{
    "ID": "1",
    "attribute1": "123"
  }
```

If I give `ID` =2,`attribute1`="456", it should return the item of subDocument like following:

```json
     {
        "ID": "2",
        "attribute1": "456",
      }
```

How can I do that?
[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xY6sPH4sY8_)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query

- adds the id/attibute of the root as subdocument
- unwind and replace `ROOT` => each member become ROOT document
- `$match` to match the document with variables

[PLayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49b3)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$project": 
   {"subDocument": 
     {"$concatArrays": 
       ["$subDocument", [{"ID": "$ID", "attribute1": "$attribute1"}]]}}},
 {"$unwind": {"path": "$subDocument"}},
 {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$subDocument"}},
 {"$match" : {"ID" : your_id_var , "attribute1" : your_attr_var}}])
```

---

**EDIT**

If you have too many fields to type them by hand, you can use this, that puts as sub-document all the fields except the `"_id"` and `"subDocument"`

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49b2)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$project": 
   {"subDocument": 
     {"$concatArrays": 
       ["$subDocument",
         [{"$arrayToObject": 
            {"$filter": 
              {"input": {"$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"},
               "cond": 
               {"$and": 
                 [{"$ne": ["$$this.k", "subDocument"]},
                  {"$ne": ["$$this.k", "_id"]}]}}}}]]}}},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$subDocument"}},
  {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$subDocument"}}
  {"$match" : {"ID" : your_id_var , "attribute1" : your_attr_var}}])
```

We dont have an operator like `remove(object,k)` so this makes object to array, fitlers and back to object (and its complicated).

There is another solution also, but its also complicated.

Comment: Thanks! If my top level document has many attributes. Do I have to list them all here when doing $concatArrays? ["$subDocument", [{"ID": "$ID", "attribute1": "$attribute1","att2":"$att2".....}]

Comment: i updated it, but my opinion is to write them by hand if possible, and keep the first query

Answer (score 3):

You can create a union of root documents and sub documents by using `$unionWith`. Then apply your filter on the union result.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "ID": 1,
      "attribute1": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "collection",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$unwind": "$subDocument"
        },
        {
          "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$subDocument"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      // your criteria here
      "ID": "2",
      "attribute1": "456",
      
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aUL8KpZVQXk) for your reference.

Comment: thanks, but $unionWith  is introduced at version 4.4. Any way to do that at version 4.2?

Comment: The accepted answer from @Takis_ should work in version 4.2. Try to understand his concept on how to create the union of documents and subdocuments.

Answer (score 1):

Do we know Why the Schema is like this where you put  ID and attribute1 at document level and also at sub document level? though we use this Schema the document returned you need is just an same filter values what you passed in Query? Is it possible that document ID and subdocument ID will clash?

Any ways still you want to get this result the use below:

If you want to persist Document & subdocument based on matching then use this :
https://mongoplayground.net/p/e0PaEvZhXIf or https://mongoplayground.net/p/d8IKfSW4h87

However now you just need whatever is matched then use below
https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ww1WqmY6wrV